# How to match underscores in photo names with mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup some cleaner looking paths to the photos I upload to my website, for easier sharing. Currently, they're stored at `/res/img/photo/{example.jpg}`, whereas I'd like to display them via `/photo/{example.jpg}`.

Most of my photos have filenames with underscores, such as `IMG_9711.jpg`. I need the rewrite rule to match any file name that has `a-zA-Z0-9` and a potential underscore, with the extension of `(JPG|PNG|GIF)`, but I'm having the hardest time trying to get mod_rewrite to work with me. How should a rewrite rule look for something like this?

Here's what I currently have, and thanks in advance.

`RewriteRule ^photo/([a-ZA-Z0-9_]+)\.(JPG|PNG|GIF)$ /res/img/photo/$1.$2 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `NC` flag for ignoring case and you can use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^photo/(\w+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$ /res/img/photo/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: That still doesn't do the trick. I've done this before, I just can't remember how, or find my old files.